# How to add a global constant to the application?

Tags: php, yii

I want to add an application constant like `YII_DEBUG`. I found that it should be defined in YiiBase class. But I don't know what is the best way to do so.

This is what the Yii documentation says

> Yii is a helper class serving common framework functionalities.
>
> It encapsulates YiiBase which provides the actual implementation. By writing your own Yii class, you can customize some functionalities of YiiBase.

How should I write my own Yii class, where should I put it and where should I call it?

Comment: Where did you find that it should be defined in `YiiBase`? That (modifying Yii sources without an *extremely* strong reason) is exactly what you must **not** do!

Comment: Not in YiiBase but in custom Yii class as in (Yii.php) which is probably extended. The text in the blockquote is from [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/Yii)

Comment: You should add a php constant to /index.php file. There is not "a best way": exists only "ways that works".

Answer (score 1):

You can define global constants in quite a few places that will get them defined automatically during request processing; the choice depends on what makes the most sense. Your options include:

1. The `index.php` [entry script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.entry) -- the constants will be usable throughout your app.
2. The [configuration file](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration), before you write `return array(...)` -- the constants will be usable throughout your app but not before [`Yii::createApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#createApplication-detail) (or the equivalent `createWebApplication`) is called.
3. The application class definition itself (wherein they can also be [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) instead of global constants). Again, the constants will be usable only after `createApplication` is called in the entry script.

If you want to define a constant as universally applicable as `YII_DEBUG` you should do as Yii does and pick option #1.

Comment: I tried the first option and it doesn't work if you put your constant before createWebApplication(). It has to be between createWebApplication() and run(), but then it doesn't follow logic of default constants. This way I will have to delete YII_DEBUG and my const will have to be set to FALSE, and I want constant with same behaviour as YII_DEBUG but different semantic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you are trying to do with this class top determine the best practice with it. The easiest way would be to set up your new class file in the vendors folder and call it, whatever, myclass.php. Then, you need to make sure is picking up the vendors folder in your config/main.php file, like so:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('myclass.php');
```

Finally, you should be able to call your new class from almost anywhere within the application, like so:

```
$myclass = new myclass();
$myclass->thisMethod();
```

There are, of course, other ways to do it. Depending on what you want you custom class to do, you might be better to use a different method, but this way will definitely get you up and running fast.